# MVC3 How to add validation errors dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, data-annotations

I am trying to show the error message on view. Can you please suggest me the right approach to do this. I was thinking to add the data annotation dynamically but can't find any solution.

Thanks

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddBook(BooksModel booksModel)
{           
    try
    {
        booksModel.Account = _bookRepository.BookDetails(booksModel.Title,booksModel.RefCode, booksModel.DontHaveRefCode);
    }
    catch (FaultException faultException)
    {
        switch (faultException.Code.Name)
        {
            case "exc1":
            // Show Error Message Here
            return View("AddBook", booksModel);
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return View("ConfirmBook", booksModel);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult AddBook(BooksModel booksModel) 
{            
    try 
    { 
        booksModel.Account = _bookRepository.BookDetails(booksModel.Title,booksModel.RefCode, booksModel.DontHaveRefCode); 
    } 
    catch (FaultException faultException) 
    { 
        switch (faultException.Code.Name) 
        { 
            case "exc1": 

            ModelState.AddModelError("", faultException);
            return View("AddBook", booksModel); 
            default: 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
   return View("ConfirmBook", booksModel); 
}
```